# No module named 'LoginForm.LoginForm'

Tags: python, django

I am creating a Django application and I am facing this issue can you please help me solve it..

**Here is the error :**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   **File "manage.py", line 21, in
>   
>       main()   File "manage.py", line 17, in main
>       execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)**
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\vaidehi.shejwalkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py",
>   line 381, in execute_from_command_line
>       utility.execute()   File "C:\Users\vaidehi.shejwalkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py",
>   line 375, in execute
>       self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File "C:\Users\vaidehi.shejwalkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
>   line 336, in run_from_argv
>       connections.close_all()   File "C:\Users\vaidehi.shejwalkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py",
>   line 219, in close_all
>       for alias in self:   File "C:\Users\vaidehi.shejwalkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py",
>   line 213, in **iter**
>       return iter(self.databases)   File "C:\Users\vaidehi.shejwalkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py",
>   line 80, in **get**
>       res = instance.**dict**[self.name] = self.func(instance)   File "C:\Users\vaidehi.shejwalkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py",
>   line 147, in databases
>       self._databases = settings.DATABASES   File "C:\Users\vaidehi.shejwalkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\conf__init__.py",
>   line 79, in **getattr**
>       self._setup(name)   File "C:\Users\vaidehi.shejwalkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\conf__init__.py",
>   line 66, in _setup
>       self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)   File "C:\Users\vaidehi.shejwalkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\conf__init__.py",
>   line 157, in **init**
>       mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)   File "C:\Users\vaidehi.shejwalkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\importlib__init__.py",
>   line 127, in import_module
>       return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "", line 1014, in _gcd_import   File
>   "", line 991, in _find_and_load   File
>   "", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked 
>   File "", line 219, in
>   _call_with_frames_removed   File "", line 1014, in _gcd_import   File "", line 991,
>   in _find_and_load   File "", line 961, in
>   _find_and_load_unlocked   File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed   File "", line 1014, in _gcd_import   File "", line 991, in _find_and_load   File "", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'LoginForm.LoginForm'

Here is what I have in my code:

**settings.py**

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'q&jl$az$6ze8ukg!_cl^&e6-3^a^a%j2m!1po(9y-_%ho)39*6'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'LoginForm.LoginForm.loginapp', // This is my app
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',



]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'LoginForm.LoginForm.urls.py'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'LoginForm.LoginForm.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

**url.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView, LogoutView
from LoginForm.LoginForm.loginapp import views as core_views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^login/', include(LoginView.as_view()), {'template_name': 'login.html'}, name='login'),
    url(r'^sign_in/', include(core_views.signup), name='sign-up'),
    url(r'^logout/$', include(LogoutView.as_view()), {'template_name': 'logout.html'}, name='logout')
]
```

**My folder structure is :**

```
LoginForm/  
 -LoginForm/  
    -loginapp/  
        -__init__.py  
        - admin.py  
        - apps.py  
        - models.py  
        - urls.py  
        - views.py  
     -Templates/  
        - base.html  
        - login.html  
        - sign_in.html  
        - logout.html  
        - home.html  
     -__init_.py  
     - apps.py  
     - settings.py  
     - urls.py 
     - wsgi.py  
 -manage.py  
 -__init__.py
```

Comment: python version?

Comment: `from LoginForm.loginapp`

Comment: python version id : 3.8.0

Comment: from LoginForm.loginapp tried this but its giving same error
of cannot find module

Comment: @VaidehiShejwalkar folder structure?

Comment: `LoginForm/

- LoginForm/
   - loginapp/
      - views.py
      - urls.py
      - views.py
      - models.py
      - apps.py
      - other...
   - Templates/
      - views.py
      - urls.py
      - views.py
      - models.py
      - apps.py
      - other...
- manage.py`

Comment: Do you have `__init__.py` in LoginForm directory? Else that wont be treated as python module

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari yes i do have it

Comment: The problem might be you should have **app** into the **project** folder your this import looks strange to me `/LoginForm /loginapp /Templates` make sure you have file created and if each folder should contain `__init__.py` . I think you should have a cleaner folder structure than what you are doing there is no meaning of keeping `views.py` inside the Templates. Or else you can install ipython and do `python manage.py shell` and see if autocomplete is letting you find the `views.py`. In my opinion cleaner structure is better here.

Comment: I have just updated it in the code you can refer my problem statement @YugandharChaudhari . Sorry I was not able to intend it in cmnt section.

So my project Name is LoginForm and app name is loginapp. loginapp , Templates and the files below template are on same level.
I hope now you can help me resolve the issue

Comment: Error is clear it will looke **into**  LoginForm base directory i.e. containing the `manage.py` you dont have `LoginForm.LoginForm` there. Your import should be `from LoginForm.loginapp import views as core_views` or `import .views as core_views` is also fine as it is in same directory but I am wondering why you are doing that? and wait a second why you have `urls.py` in app ? it is supposed to be in **project** not  in **app** for routing

Comment: Initially I have used `from LoginForm.loginapp import views as core_views` this only, but it gave me error. so i copied the relative path and used it. and the relative path is `from LoginForm.LoginForm.loginapp import views as core_views`. and if i used this it doesn't give me error while writing code but while running the server it throws no module found error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202037/discussion-between-yugandhar-chaudhari-and-vaidehi-shejwalkar).

Comment: @VaidehiShejwalkar Yes because in root there is only one LoginForm folder

Answer (score 0):

If your repository looks like:

```
project/
- settings.py
- urls.py
- other...
LoginForm/
- views.py
- models.py
- apps.py
- other...
manage.py
```

You should have something like :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'LoginForm.apps.loginapp', #So: <directory_name>/apps(corresponding to apps.py)/<Class name in the file>
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Hope it'll help you.

Comment: Also, in **urls.py**, try to use `from loginapp import views as core_views`
You don't have to declare the main folder

Comment: @HugoMartin this is not an answer for OPs problem

Comment: Can you be more clear about your problem ? You are talking to me about sys.path but where ?
And I still maintain that the mistake comes from the path you enter for the module.

Comment: @HugoMartin in urls.py if I use `from loginapp import views as core_views` then it shows error I need to use full relative path for loginapp.